# Implantar App Node.js em localhost(Produção)

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows

Desenvolvi uma aplicação com Angular + Node.js.

O único detalhe é que não há um servidor centralizado(Node.js), ou seja, cada cliente vai ter a sua versão do servidor rodando em sua rede.

Devido a isso, tive de criar formas de instalar o app em Node.js de modo fácil em cada cliente, testei uma alternativa que não teve o retorno esperado:

- Instalar o App como serviço do windows

Onde fiz um .bat com os comandos para instalação de dependências, adição das portas no firewall, instalação dos serviços, etc..

Para fazer isso usei a lib "node-windows" : https://github.com/coreybutler/node-windows

Porém, na maioria dos computadores não executa o script. É preciso executar de novo, as vezes acusa erro de permissão, em outras aparece no console que deu certo, mas na hora de conferir os serviços. eles não estão lá, enfim.. Fiz vários testes, alterações e não resolveu.

Diante disso, gostaria de saber:

- Quais alternativas eu tenho para instalar o App em (Node.js) em máquinas locais?(Estou falando em produção, não em testes ou DEV).
- Existe alguma forma transparente ou simplificada("Gerar um executável"?! Talvez)
- Li em alguns locais que é utilizado o IIS para hospedar a aplicação, alguém já teve experiência nesse sentido, tem algum exemplo do funcionamento?

Comment: Já testei com IIS. Não fica muito bom não, tem que instalar uma coisarada pra funcionar. Acho que uma boa forma de fazer o que você quer é criar um [`docker`](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/) com tudo que você precisa e apenas executa-lo no cliente.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se sua aplicação utiliza Node + Angular, uma possibilidade é a geração de um executável via [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/).

Ele já vem com o Node.js embutido. Entretanto, você pode utilizar pacotes npm e [gerar instaladores](https://github.com/electron/windows-installer) contendo todos os módulos em uso, com a vantagem que o usuário não precisa instalar nenhum browser específico (já que a engine do Electron é por si só uma versão do Chrome).

Comment: Bacana @OnoSendai, Eu já tinha ouvido falar do Electron, mas não havia pensando nessa possibilidade(nem sabia que dava pra fazer). Porém como ficaria a estrutura do projeto, jogaria os dois projetos que tenho(Cliente e Servidor) dentro de um novo projeto electron? Se não for pedir demais, poderias mostrar um exemplo básico de uso?

Comment: @Geferson em vários projetos que implementei, essa foi a escolha - tanto o conteúdo estático (cliente) quanto o back-end eram embutidos na mesma solução. Um excelente exemplo pode ser estudado aqui: https://scotch.io/tutorials/creating-desktop-applications-with-angularjs-and-github-electron